# Div Won't Adjust to adjusting browser window

Tags: css, html, space

I am very new to web design, so I might be completely over my head here.. but I can not seem to figure out how to work this. I have an image inside my first div, underneath this I want to have to more divs with the background colors in which I will add content. But for some reason my divs are not adjusting with the browser. Everytime I adjust the browser to be smaller, the divs backgrounds are separating and a white space is coming in between them.

Any help would be highly appreciated.. Also any critical feedback on my obvious coding skills, would be highly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class= "header">
<div class="large-logo-wrap">
<img src="Assets/Giadaslogoindexwhitebig.png" draggable="false"></img>
</div>
<div class="middle">
</div>
<div class="end">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
width:100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.header{
width:100%;
height:768px;
background-image: url('Assets/header.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
.large-logo-wrap {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 700px;
}
.middle{
position: absolute;
top: 768px;
background-color: rgb(229,225,209);
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-size: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
 }
.end{
position: absolute;
top: 1500px;
background-color: rgb(29,25,29);
width: 100%;
height:768px;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

be nice. Cheers!

Comment: A lot of your code is wrong. For example, img elements are self closing. `<img src="http://yoursource" alt="logo" />` Your divs aren't all closing properly. A lot of your CSS is unnecessary. Divs and other block level elements are 100% width by default. I'll make a jsfiddle and see if we can get to a cleaner starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a closer look at the code and strip out as much as you can to see what is actually necessary to get where you are going. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/y25z5/) with some cleaned up code that does what I think you are going for. Hopefully it helps.

### HTML

```
<header class="container global-header">
    <div class="inner-w">
        <div class="large-logo-wrap">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<section class="container section01">
    <div class="inner-w">
        Middle - arbitrary set height - I suggest you let the content decide the height
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container section02">
    <div class="inner-w">
        Other section - arbitrary set height
    </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after { /* get your box model so that padding and margins go inside the box instead of outside, and add to the overall size of the box */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container { /* things the sections have in common */
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.inner-w {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05); /* just so you can see */
    /* by using an inner div in your container... you allow yourself to maintain a background-color across the whole page if you wish. If you don't want that, then you just style the inner div for each section with the background color */
}

.global-header {
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center; /* centers inline, and inline-block elements (logo) */
}

.large-logo-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 8em; /* set max image size */
}

.large-logo-wrap img { /* responsive image */
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; /* fits whatever you set the wrapper to */
    height: auto;
}

.section01 { /* arbitray section */
    background-color: rgb(229,225,209);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    min-height: 234px; /* if you absolutly must - choose a height... use min */
}

.section02 { /* arbitray section */
    background-color: rgb(29,25,29);
    color: rgb(229,225,209);
    min-height: 346px; /* if you absolutly must - choose a height... use min */
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help. 

I am really a beginner here and trying to mash up tutorials to try and get what I want.. but you are right, I am sure a LOT of it is wrong or unnecessary. What you provided looks like exactly what I want, only problem is that behind my logo I want an image instead of the light blue. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it sure is.     

`background-image: url("http://your/image-path.jpg");`
`background-size: cover;` to start.

Comment: Updated the fiddle as well. Good luck.

Comment: The window is relative by default. relative is a boundary for things positioned absolutely inside of it. You can make anything relative and therefor a nested boundary to absolutely position. Many professional developers don't actually understand this. Learn positioning, the difference between inline, block, and inline-block --- and start mobile first. Take it slow. The quicker you want instant gratification the faster you will skip over the most essential parts. This stuff is easy if you think about it in the right way. Think of each major section of your site as it's own mini website.

Comment: PS - I can't say any of these answers actually answer your question... which was - "why isn't this working." --- but don't forget to mark things as answered if you feel like you get an answer.

Comment: oops! sorry. You did answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `css` with this one:

```
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.container{
width:100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.header{
width:100%;
height:768px;
background-image: url('Assets/header.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.large-logo-wrap {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 700px;
}

.middle{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 700px;
background-color: rgb(229,225,209);
 }

.end{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 700px;
background-color: rgb(29,25,29);
}
```

Some of your `css` styles were wrong, for example you used `width` and `height` with `%100` which is  wrong and effects on all of your `css` styles.
Also, you used `position:absolute` for all of div which effects on `div` to be nonadjustable.